# Reading multiple files with Javascript FileReader API one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

I'm using the **FileReader** API to read multiple files.

```
<html> <body>
    <input type="file" id="filesx" name="filesx[]"
      onchange="readmultifiles(this.files)" multiple=""/>
    <div id="bag"><ul/></div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
        alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
    }
}

function readmultifiles(files) {
    var ul = document.querySelector("#bag>ul");
    while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    }

    function setup_reader(file) {
        var name = file.name;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var bin = e.target.result; //get file content

            // do sth with text

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = name;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { setup_reader(files[i]); }
}
</script> </body> </html>
```

The problem is that all files are read at the same time, and when the files have a total size (sum) that is very large, the browser crashes.

I want to read one file after another, so that the memory consumption is reduced.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just implemented solution for this, would recommend this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975129/984471

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I came up with a solution myself which works.

```
function readmultifiles(files) {
  var reader = new FileReader();  
  function readFile(index) {
    if( index >= files.length ) return;
    var file = files[index];
    reader.onload = function(e) {  
      // get file content  
      var bin = e.target.result;
      // do sth with bin
      readFile(index+1)
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
  readFile(0);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a new [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object for each read? I believe the FileReader object is not meant to be reused after it's state had changed from `0` (empty) to `1` (loading), and then to `2` (done).  This might give you some serious browser bugs.

Comment: Nice recursive function.

Comment: If I use "reader.addListener('load', callback)". It will be double at last item.

Answer (score 23):

I'm updating this question for the benefit of new users, who are looking for a solution to upload multiple files via [the FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader), especially using ES.

Rather than manually iterating over each file, it's much simpler & cleaner to use [`Object.keys(files)` in ES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
<input type="file" onChange="readmultifiles" multiple/>
<script>
function readmultifiles(e) {
  const files = e.currentTarget.files;
  Object.keys(files).forEach(i => {
    const file = files[i];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      //server call for uploading or reading the files one-by-one
      //by using 'reader.result' or 'file'
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  })
};
</script>
```

Comment: Array.from(files).foreach(file => {}) also works nice

Comment: For some reason this seems more javascript-ey solution to me than the accepted one.

Answer (score 18):

This should read the files one by one:

```
function readmultifiles(files) {
    var ul = document.querySelector("#bag>ul");
    while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    }
    // Read first file
    setup_reader(files, 0);
}

// Don't define functions in functions in functions, when possible.

function setup_reader(files, i) {
    var file = files[i];
    var name = file.name;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
                        readerLoaded(e, files, i, name);
                    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    // After reading, read the next file.
}

function readerLoaded(e, files, i, name) {
    // get file content  
    var bin = e.target.result;
    // do sth with text

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = name;
    ul.appendChild(li);

    // If there's a file left to load
    if (i < files.length - 1) {
        // Load the next file
        setup_reader(files, i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good one especially when you need which file had completed onload so you can take file.type, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Define the input using `multiple` property:

```
<input onchange = 'upload(event)' type = 'file' multiple/>
```

Define the upload function:

```js
const upload = async (event) => {
  
    // Convert the FileList into an array and iterate
    let files = Array.from(event.target.files).map(file => {

        // Define a new file reader
        let reader = new FileReader();

        // Create a new promise
        return new Promise(resolve => {

            // Resolve the promise after reading file
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);

            // Read the file as a text
            reader.readAsText(file);

        });

    });

    // At this point you'll have an array of results
    let res = await Promise.all(files);
  
}
```

Comment: This solution should be accepted

Answer (score 3):

My complete solution is here:

```
 <html> <body>
    <input type="file" id="filesx" name="filesx[]"
      onchange="readmultifiles(this.files)" multiple=""/>
    <div id="bag"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
        alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
    }
}

function readmultifiles(files) {
  var reader = new FileReader();  
  function readFile(index) {
    if( index >= files.length ) return;
    var file = files[index];
    reader.onload = function(e) {  
      // get file content  
      var bin = e.target.result;
      // do sth with bin
      readFile(index+1)
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
  readFile(0);

 function setup_reader(file) {
        var name = file.name;
        var reader = new FileReader();

            var ul = document.createElement("ul");
            document.getElementById('bag').appendChild(ul);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var bin = e.target.result; //get file content

            // do sth with text

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = name;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { setup_reader(files[i]); }
}
</script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: This solution is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I implemented another solution using modern JS (Map, Iterator). I adapted the code from my Angular application (originally written with some TS features).

Like Steve KACOU mentioned, we create a different FileReader instance for each file.

```html
<input type="file" id="filesx" name="filesx[]"
      onchange="processFileChange(this)" multiple=""/>
```

```js
    function processFileChange(event) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
            const fileMap = new Map();

            for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
                const file = event.target.files[i];
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileMap.set(fileReader, file);
            }

            const mapEntries = fileMap.entries();
            readFile(mapEntries);
        }
    }

    function readFile(mapEntries) {
        const nextValue = mapEntries.next();

        if (nextValue.done === true) {
            return;
        }

        const [fileReader, file] = nextValue.value;

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        fileReader.onload = () => {
            // Do black magic for each file here (using fileReader.result)

            // Read the next file
            readFile(mapEntries);
        };
    }
```

Basically this takes advantage of passing objects by reference to perpetuate the map with every iteration. This makes the code quite easy to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the best parts of these answers.

```html
<input type="file" onchange="readmultifiles(this.files)" multiple />
<script>
function readmultifiles(files) {
  for (file of files) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    reader.fileName = file.name;
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const fileName = event.target.fileName;
      const content = event.currentTarget.result;
      console.log({ fileName, content });
    };
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this will not fix the issue of him *not* wanting files read in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You must **instantiate a FileReader for each file** to read.

```js
function readFiles(event) {
  //Get the files
  var files = event.input.files || [];
  if (files.length) {
    for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
      //instantiate a FileReader for the current file to read
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        var result = reader.result;
        console.log(result); //File data
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will read the files in parallel. The OP asked for an implementation where they can be read sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const setFileMultiple = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get the files
  let file = [...e.target.files] || [];

  file.forEach((item, index) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      console.log("result", reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file[index]);
  });

};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).