# How to use FileReader for two or more input fields in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am wondering how to use **FileReader** in vue js if I have to get images upload from two or more different input fields (tags). I have been copying and pasting the same code below to different functions in order to upload files but i think that there should be a better way.

```
bImage(event) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = event => {
        this.form.images.push(event.target.result);
        console.log(event.target.result);
      };
    },
```

Comment: This can be found on stackoverflow already on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975031/reading-multiple-files-with-javascript-filereader-api-one-at-a-time

Comment: No, no I know how to add multiple images but I am having problem when i use filereader for uploading files from different input fields inside a same form. Although I have five input fields for file, the image data gets bound to only one input field and other remain unchanged, Can you help me?

Comment: Whats the issue? Above should work?

Comment: @Estradiaz The above code worked but if i use more than two input fields for file upload only one data gets the value of filereader output, others remain empty.

Comment: hmm maybe show us your implementation of whats not working then? how do you use it on more?